# How do I bypass certificate security check in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, asp.net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been working on a Xamarin app which gets data from the JSON(which is ASPNET Core Web API) but when I used HTTPS Protocol in my app, it threw an error of "trust anchor for certification path not found"

After some experimenting, I disabled HTTPS from the application and tried it solely with HTTP, at which point the app deployed flawlessly on the emulator. Nevertheless, in order to deploy it to actual devices, I want to run it over HTTPS yet again. Does it still need to be done if I use HTTPS? What disadvantages come with utilising solely HTTP Protocol?